# find not working with Perl rename with Linux - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to rename a large amount of files within several directories recursively. I'm on Ubuntu Linux.

Last night I made a mistake leading to all of my files and directories being renamed with the prefix, "L" like e.g.
`folder1/file1.img -> Lfolder1/Lfile1.im`
`folder2/file2.img -> Lfolder2/Lfile2.img`
`folder3/file3.img -> Lfolder3/Lfile3.img`

I'm using the Perl rename function:

```
rename 's/^L//' *
```

This works on it's own, within 1 directory, but pairing it with "find" and "exec" to work recursively doesn't work, like this:

```
find . -depth -exec rename 's/^L//' {} +
```

I've tried using "-execdir" and playing around with the syntax while not committing any changes but I can't get it to work.

On it's own this returns the full recursive list of directories as well which is very weird.

```
find .
```

This works on 1 directory, but not the subdirectories, see result effect:

```
rename 's/^L//' *
```

`Lfolder1/Lfile1.img -> folder1/Lfile1.img`
`Lfolder2/Lfile2.img -> folder2/Lfile2.img`
`Lfolder3/Lfile3.img -> folder3/Lfile3.img`

I have tried this, and it also doesn't return anything. Inserting "echo" after the exec command returns the list of files, though, but it does not seem to be passing them to the rename command:

```
find . -depth -exec rename 's/^L//' {} +
```

Does anyone know how to target directories recursively, and fix this issue? I'm looking to, after I've fixed my mistake, rename all of the files and directories to lower-case.

Comment: There are Perl modules for `find` that removes the need for shell commands, e.g. `File::Find` and `File::Find::Rule`.

Answer (score 3):

The filenames, as you can see from using `echo` as the `-execdir` parameter, contain the leading `./`, so `^L` doesn't really match any of them. You need to switch to `/L` instead, and to avoid the leaning toothpick syndrome, switch to a different delimiter.

```
find . -depth -execdir rename 's=/L=/=' {} \;
```

The `-depth` is still needed, otherwise the directories are renamed before their contents and find isn't able to enter them.

Comment: Note that I had to remove `.` from my PATH for this command to run. ("find: The current directory is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove the current directory from your $PATH (that is, remove ".", doubled colons, or leading or trailing colons)") Providing an absolute path to `rename` did not remove that requirement to remove `.` from my PATH.

Comment: Yeah, I needed to precede the line with `PATH=${PATH%:.}`. I don't agree with people who say that `.` is dangerous in the $PATH (I only do it for non-root users and always at the end of the $PATH).

Comment: In this particular case, it could be "dangerous" in the sense that it might execute a `rename` found in the searched directory instead the intended one. That's why it objects for `-execdir` but not `-exec`. And that's why I thought providing the full path to `rename` might avoid the issue.

Comment: @ikegami: If the dot is the last in $PATH, it shouldn't execute the other rename (if there's any rename in any of the searched directories, of course).

Comment: But if it's at the front (and it often is), then it could. That's what the check is all about. (Even if it's at the back, you could have a problem is `rename` is not in your PATH at all.)

Answer (score 1):

You pass `Lfolder1/Lfile1.img` first, intending to have it renamed to `Lfolder1/file1.img`, but that's not the `L` that's matched!

Solution:

```bash
find . -depth -exec rename -d 's/^L//' {} +
```

`-d` causes the directory to be stripped before the provided code is executed, and re-added afterwards.